# MariaDB Error "Current position is after the last row" when trying to insert

Tags: java, exception, insert, mariadb

I am developing a Java application version 1.8.0.60, the mariadb jdbc client is version 1.2.0

When I try to insert a record into one of the tables I get an exception: 
"Current position is after the last row"

However if I copy the exact INSERT statement and use HeidiSQL to insert, it works without any error, as far as I can see there is nothing wrong with the SQL.

INSERT INTO `tblModbusData` (
`mintAddress`,`tintSEM`,`tintModule`,`tintChannel` 
) VALUES ( 
'301001','1','1','0')

Why?

Comment: Can you post the Java code used for the insertion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by wrapping the SQL into a stored procedure and executing that:

CALL funCreateModbusEntry(301001,1,1,0);

No more error, the java execute code was exactly the same:

Statement st = mcon.createStatement();
st.executeUpdate(strSQL, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

Thats simiplified but basically it.